# How to fix "Unsupported Language for TypeScript" in Visual Studio 2013？

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I don't know whether my question is asked or not but I didn't find after searching a lot:( And my problem is that I downloaded the TypeScript from this website: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790, **this declears that it supports both 2012 and 2013**.

But now the question is when I wrote all the typescript codes and do compilation in VS2012 (Not English version), everything goes well with me, but in VS2013, it cannot compile at all but gives me a compling error——Not supported Language "xxxxx"

Questsion: **Why & How to fix that problem?** This is my complication error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: But I tried and found this:

1) It can be really installed inn VS2013 but English version ONLY.

2) It writes "2013" in his topic……?

Comment: Where can I find that? It seems that when I right click and I cannot find the type "ts"? Can u give me a torturial or something? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it has been available in RC but hidden in RTM, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/10/17/typescript-and-the-road-to-1-0.aspx

Comment: Yes that's the PROBLEM……I've clicked that and that pops me a webiste to Microsoft's TypeScript, just like what I gave you above, have u tried that? I have to think it doesn't support non-English version of VS2013;)

Comment: I have provided the answer and that's currently unavoidable. The TypeScript guys know it and should fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been marked as a known issue of current TypeScript release,

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1606

Thus, you will have to stick to VS2012 and wait till a new release of TypeScript is published.